# In the Backus-Naur Form what does a comma ',' mean while defining a symbol

Tags: concurrency, bnf

I am as much newbie to Pi-Calculus as I am with Backus Naur Form.
Here is one of the core BNF for Pi Calculus ( found in "Applied Pi - A Brief Tutorial" by Peter Sewell)

```
P,Q ::= 0                        nil
        P | Q                    parallel composition of P and Q
        ~cv                      output v on channel c
        cw.P                     input from channel c
        new c in P               new channel name creation
```

In deed I am focussed on learning Pi Calculus. But I do wonder about the meaning of P,Q ::= in the definition of the BNF.

I would understand P ::= meaning that a process P of Pi calculus is this or this or this.
But what P,Q ::= stands for ?

Comment: I am still searching... but so far all examples of BNF I can see only define one term/symbol. Not two symbols seperated by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, this means that the letters `P` and `Q` are both used to denote processes. For example, in `P | Q`, `P` is a process and `Q` is a process. The author could have written

```
P ::= 0
      P1 | P2
      ~cv
      cw.P
      new c in P
```

but preferred to allow two distinct letters to refer to the same concept in order to make formulas a bit more readable.

By the way, classically the alternatives in BNF are separated by a vertical bar; but since the vertical bar `|` has a meaning in pi-calculus, the author didn't want to use them both in their pi-calculus meaning and in their BNF meaning. The definition should still be read as “a process is either nil, or a parallel composition, or …”.

Comment: Many thanx. It makes more sense.